# Excel VBA compatibility issues between Office 2013 + Win7 and Office 2013 + Win10

Tags: vba, excel

Say you have 10 users(numbers are arbitrary):

- 7 users use Windows 7 with Office 2013, both 32-bit
- 3 users use Windows 10 (64-bit) with Office 2013 (32-bit)

The Windows 10 users have 2 errors when trying to use a macro:

1. On opening the macro, they receive an error about a missing file on their system
2. When the form/controls begin to load, they receive a compile error message

The first error was fixed by removing a reference to Common Controls (mscomct2.ocx).

The second error is caused by ComboBoxes that are used as DatePickers. These ComboBoxes are not loaded at all on the Win10 systems.

```
cboFillerName = Date
```

The problem is that the macro works perfectly for the 7 users, but it doesn't work for any of the 3 users. The only difference between them is Windows 10.

So is there some API difference between the two operating systems that would cause this? Is it the mixture of Win10/Office 2013 (32-bit) that creates a convoluted scenario where ComboBoxes can't be used as Date Pickers?

I cannot provide any specific code, though I don't think that matters as this problem does not seem to be code related.

Comment: IIR, configuring as Date Pickers requires mscomct2.ocx. I just late binds.

Comment: @Comintern Therein lies the conundrum. The macro needs the file, but the file causes it to error...

Comment: As long as the office installation is 32-bit, you *could* just distribute the .ocx file - it would be running in a 32-bit context.  The other option would be to find a different ActiveX control to use, but you'd need to distribute that too.  The only other option would be to hand-roll your own date picker, maybe as a UserForm. This is basically just a deployment issue until you have to support 64-bit Office.

Comment: I had come to the same conclusions. Tried putting the ocx file on one of the Win10 systems. It resulted in bringing the first error back, while keeping the second error, though the reference to the file was no longer listed as "Missing". Got any more ideas? Don't want to jump right into making my own date picker..